# HTML forms, fwrite and PHP

Tags: php, xampp, fwrite, fieldset

I want to use fwrite to save data into a .txt file. The action method seems to be working, as it can show HTML tags when being transfered when pressing submit, but i wont run the PHP.

```
<HTML lang="da">
<style>
</style>

<header>
    <title>Tilføj</title>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
</header>

<body>

<form method="post" action="eksamen_save_data.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Filmoplysninger</legend>
                <div><label>Titel: <input type="text" name="titel" id="titel" required="required" size="60" maxlength="100"></label></div>
                <div><label>Hovedskuespiller: <input type="text" name="hovedskuespiller" id="hovedskuespiller" required="required" size="30" maxlength="100"></label></div>
                <div><label>Genre: <input type="text" name="genre" id="genre" required="required" size="60" maxlength="100"></label></div>
                <div><label>Format: <input type="text" name="format" id="format" required="required" size="60" maxlength="100"></label></div>
                <div><label>Billede: <input type="file" name="billede" id="billede" required="required"></label></div>
        </fieldset>

        <div><input type="submit" id="ok" value="OK"></div>
    </form>

</body>
```

This sends it to the "eksamen_save_data.php" that looks like this:

```
<?php
        $Titel = $_POST["titel"];
        $Hovedskuespiller = $_POST["hovedskuespiller"];
        $Genre = $_POST["genre"];
        $Format = $_POST["format"];
        //$Billede = $_FILES["billede"]["navn"];

        //if($_FILES){
        //  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["billed"]["navn"], $_FILES["billed"]["navn"]);
        //}

        $user_data = "$Titel, $Hovedskuespiller, $Genre, $Format, $Billede \r\n";

        $fh = fopen("data.txt", "a") or die("Fejl i åbning af fil!");
        fwrite($fh, $user_data) or die ("Fejl i skrivning til fil!");
        fclose($fh);
?>
```

If i write some HTML in the "eksamen_save_data.php" i can show this, but it wont run the PHP. I'm using XAMPP.
The problem is that it wont save to the "data.txt" file as i tell the PHP to do.

Another question; is there also a way, I can make the PHP run in the same file as where I have my fieldset?

LAST EDIT:

Most of the time it's the little mistakes that proves to be the biggest problem. For me i personally forgot to use: localhost/eksamen_tilføj.php in the browser.

So it was me making a mistake in XAMPP.

Comment: what do you mean by *it won't run the PHP* ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific. It will not save into the file I want it to. If I type an input and submit it, it wont save it into the "data.txt" file.

Comment: Check if sure `eksamen_save_data.php` in the same directory as `data.txt`

Comment: Try debugging the ```$_FILES["billede"]``` var. Also, ```$_FILES["billede"]["navn"]``` is different from ```$_FILES["billed"]["navn"]```

Comment: maybe am wrong but $_FILES dont have anything call `navn` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php ,also the `move_uploaded_file` take 2 arguments `temp_dir, target_dir` which cant be the same ,also instead of `fwrite` better use `file_get_contents` & `file_put_contents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **file_put_contents**

```
file_put_contents("data.txt", $user_data, FILE_APPEND);
```

It does all the jobs like file open, write and close. Advantage is if the file does not exist then it will create.

**Find full working code**

```
<?php
        $Titel = $_POST["titel"];
        $Hovedskuespiller = $_POST["hovedskuespiller"];
        $Genre = $_POST["genre"];
        $Format = $_POST["format"];
        $Billede = $_FILES["billede"]["name"];
// Example of accessing data for a newly uploaded file
$fileName = $_FILES["billede"]["name"]; 
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["billede"]["tmp_name"];
// Path and file name
$pathAndName = "upload/".$fileName;
// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed
if ($moveResult == true) {
    echo "File has been moved from " . $fileTmpLoc . " to" . $pathAndName;
} else {
     echo "ERROR: File not moved correctly";
} 

        $user_data = "$Titel, $Hovedskuespiller, $Genre, $Format, $Billede \r\n";
 file_put_contents("data.txt", $user_data, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this now, but without any results. I'm thinking this may be an issue with my code, as I really think the code should work.

Either by using file_put_contents or the fwrite, there's not getting anything written into my file.

Comment: Can you spot the data.txt file

Comment: Try echoing  $user_data before file_put_contents

Comment: This seems to be a problem. Nothing happens when i echo $user_data;.

Comment: Find my edited answer. Create a folder called upload in php file's directory

Comment: Thank you a lot for you time here in the busy christmas/new year time.
I marked this as right, as it works! The problem i had made was due to me making a mistake in XAMPP not using localhost/dir.

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to remove the third parameter `$test` (because it specifies the length of the content to be written). But `$test` is not defined in your PHP file, so it won't write anything..

So change this

`fwrite($fh, $user_data, $test) or die ("Fejl i skrivning til fil!");`

into this

`fwrite($fh, $user_data) or die ("Fejl i skrivning til fil!");`

and have a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) :)

Comment: I had added the $test because i wanted to try something, which didn't work. I tried changing it back, but it wont seem to work. What I'm beginning to think is, that it might be my XAMPP messing me up, because I really can't see why the code don't work.

I had a look at your link and it should follow the correct parameters now. Any other ideas are more then welcome! :)

Comment: maybe it has to do with the file/folder permissions. So try checking the file permissions for data.txt

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question: sure you can merge your form and submit scripts:

```
<?php
if(count($_POST) > 0) { // 
    /** Form submit function, file write **/
} else {
?>
<html>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<!-- Enter HTMLform here -->
</form>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

This pseudocode is not pretty, but will do in terms of explaining stuff. The `#` in the form action means that the same script is to be called upon submission. The `if(count($_POST) > 0)` checks whether data has been submitted. If so, the file will be written. Otherwise, the form will be displayed.

Good luck.